# Is it possible to create a shortcut to a Window console app that starts hidden?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, console

I'd like to start a console app upon startup, but I'd like it not to clutter the taskbar with a cmd.exe item. The options I have when editing a shortcut are only "Normal window", "Minimized", and "Maximized". I faintly remember some Windows version having "Hidden" as an option. I'm using Windows 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem too, I wrote a small app that does this: http://miffthefox.googlepages.com/silentcmd.

Comment: I used your solution. Nice little utility.

Comment: Here is [another implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56111754/70405) if you care about text output of hidden console app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .vbs file with the following

```
Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 12

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")

Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
objConfig.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
errReturn = objProcess.Create("Cmd.exe /c C:\run.bat", null, objConfig, intProcessID)
```

And replace

```
"Cmd.exe /c C:\run.bat"
```

with your silent command

Comment: Wow, that is a lot of work for what the WScript.Shell object already exposes with it's .Run method.

Comment: Didn't work. It starts and ends, doesn't print any message when I run it from a command prompt. What I'm trying to run is the Folding@Home client, fah6.exe. I don't want to run it as a service.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(VS.85).aspx) from the MSDN setting `intWindowStyle` (one of the arguments to WScript.Shell.Run) to 0

> Hides the window and activates another window.

Though it also states:

> *intWindowStyle*
>   Optional. Integer value indicating the appearance of the
>   program's window. Note that not all
>   programs make use of this information.